# have to shift tabindex between two HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class=" yellow" data-name="notes" title="View Notes">
        <div class="title">
            <h3 id="notesid" >notes</h3>

            <div class="info">
                <a href="#" id="clear-notes" title="Clear notes">Clear</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body">

            <div class="content-area notes-area resizeble" style="height: 130px;">

                <textarea   title="Notes" id="notes-textarea" rows="5" cols="15">Notes</textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

In this code, I have a div with two focusable elements---- anchor element and a text area. By default the focus is first on anchor and then on textarea but I need to exchange the focus. According to me , Textarea wud be the first element to focus and anchor element second. Can anyone help me out in this... Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery or HTML5 needed, just the old [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.tabindex) attribute:

```html
<div class=" yellow" data-name="notes" title="View Notes">
    <div class="title">
         <h3 id="notesid">notes</h3>
        <div class="info"> <a href="#" id="clear-notes" title="Clear notes" tabindex="2">Clear</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content-area notes-area resizeble" style="height: 130px;">
            <textarea title="Notes" id="notes-textarea" rows="5" cols="15" tabindex="1">Notes</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes..no doubt its a simple solution but I have so many elements in my web page nd i dont want to explicitly define tabindex of all elements in the page.. All elements are focusing in good way irrespective of these two elements. So want a jquery for for fixing the relative tabindexes of these elements only –

Answer (score 0):

You can define the order by using tabindex

e.g. `tabindex="1"`

While in HTML 5 this works on all HTML elements it also works in HTML 4.01. But not on all types of elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: yes..but i dont want to explicitly define tabindex of all elements in the page.. All elements are focusing in good way irrespective of these two elements. So want a jquery for for fixing the relative tabindexes of these elements only